# Is it possible to tint vector drawable with ColorStateList

Tags: android, svg, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

Now I have something like

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Where bg_button_selected, bg_button_pressed, bg_button_normal are very same PNG's, the only difference is color.

Can I replace set of PNG's with single SVG and set tint to it somehow like this?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/bg_color_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/bg_color_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/bg_color_normal"/>
</selector>
```

And is it possible for pre Lollipop devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can with Support Library.

You can use [ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(View, ColorStateList)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.view.View,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)).

Comment: Cool, can I do that in XML?

Comment: Yes you can. Assuming you are using a `Button`, you are actually using a `AppCompatButton` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html .
In your XML you can just add `app:backgroundTint="@color/tintColor` with your generic color state list.